# The meaning of an "inconclusive" answer

Tags: word-meaning

> If you show a picture to a three-year-old and ask if there is a tree in it, you will likely get the correct answer. If you ask a thirty-year-old what the definition of a tree is, you will likely get an **inconclusive answer**.

Longman says:

> not leading to a clear decision or result  OPP  conclusive :
>   The evidence against the two men was inconclusive. 
>   A coalition government was formed after inconclusive elections.

What could be the answer of the child to be an inconclusive answer. I mean what is the meaning of inconclusive answer in this context? does it mean unclear and ambiguous? because I don't think that we want to get a decision over the answer of the child!

I also request for an example.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @TRomano I mean an example of an inconclusive answer to get its meaning.

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of "[inconclusive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inconclusive)"?  It means "not leading to a conclusion" or "not leading to anything definite or specific".

Comment: What is the source of your example? I don't think *inconclusive* is the best choice here. Also, a dictionary definition of *inconclusive* and how you understand it needs to be added to your question.

Comment: @user3169 I added more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Inconclusive" means "not leading to a conclusion, vague, not specific".

What the writer is saying here is that if you asked an adult to give a definition of a common word, such as "tree", you would often get a vague, not-specific answer. If you had never seen a tree before and had never heard of the idea of a tree -- perhaps you grew up in New York City :-) -- and then someone tried to explain to you what a tree was, you might have great difficulty going out into the wild and identifying what is a tree and what is not.

But ask any child whether that thing over there is or is not a tree and he will almost always give you a correct answer without a moment's hesitation.

The point is, There are lots of things in the world that we all know what we mean when we call them by some name, but most of us would have a very hard time explaining exactly what we mean by that name.

Like if you asked the average person to define "tree", you might end up with a conversation like this:

> Average: A tree is a thing that grows in the ground.
>
> Pedant: Oh, like this flower? This flower is a kind of tree?
>
> Average: No no, a tree is bigger than that.
>
> Pedant: So this sprouting oak, this isn't a tree because it's too small?
>
> Average: Well, I'd call that a sapling, but I guess it's still a kind of tree.
>
> Pedant: So size isn't the issue? A flower is a tree?
>
> Average: Well, it has to be made of wood, you know, be hard.
>
> Pedant: Oh!! So this fence post. It's coming out of the ground and it's hard and made of wood. So it's a tree.
>
> Average: No, it has to be alive.
>
> Pedant: Ok, how about this mulberry bush then? It's alive and growing and made of wood.

Etc.

Every now and then on this site someone will say that he found an unfamiliar English word, looked it up in the dictionary, and the dictionary definition didn't seem to make sense. And often the explanation is, Yes, coming up with clear, unambiguous definitions is hard, and even professional dictionary-writers have a hard time of it.

Answer (score 3):

An inconclusive answer is an answer from which you can draw no conclusions. For instance, if you asked me " Is the sky blue?" And I said "Yes", you'd have a conclusive answer. If however I replied " The sky is not green", you'd have an inconclusive answer - It's an answer, but it doesn't give you enough information to satisfy what you asked or wanted to know.